# PyCharm 2019.2.1 PEP8 line length checking works wrong

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm Community version on Win10. After one of the last updates PyCharm PEP8 style checking started to incorrectly underline words by the reason of PEP8 line length rule violation. Example:
[image: wrong underline example]
or
[image: wrong underline example 2]

Example for copy and error reproduction (it will raise PEP 8: line too long (200 > 120 characters) on the symbol `=`):

```
# матрицы ограничений (первый вектор - функция, второй вектор - значение меньше или равно которого эта функция)
a_list = []
```

I assume that the error is related to the Cyrillic symbols. If I delete comment on line 2 from the first example, string `'project'` will no longer be underlined. Anyways I had no problems with the Cyrillic until this time.

Is it bug? How I can fix this behaviour of style checking without disable line checking? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known issue with Cyrillic comments indeed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37054

Either fix a bundled `pycodestyle` copy manually: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37054#focus=streamItem-27-3609146.0-0

or install PyCharm 2019.2.2 Preview build https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23004355